# from excel with grouped rows to elasticsearch (using python to create the index)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

Having an excel with grouped rows (as in the picture), for this data **Test1**, **Test2** and **Test3** are the main tasks, and the other lines are subtasks, I would like to have the same format on elasticsearch (using python to create the index). [link for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCscj.png)

```
json_str = generate_data(df_test).to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')

json_records = json.loads(json_str)

action_list=[]
for row in json_records:
    record ={
        '_op_type': 'index',
        '_index': index_name,
        '_source': row
    }
    action_list.append(record)

helpers.bulk(es, action_list)
```

Comment: Parse CSV file and push the data to ES ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I already did that, but what I would like to have is to separate each subset of tasks, for example if I type Test1 in the kibana search bar, I will have Test1 and its subtasks

Comment: I've just added my code that push data to ES. That's what i've done so far because i don't know how to modelise my tasks and subtasks.